# Create scope for many to many relationship rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, scope, many-to-many, join

I want to create scope in Company model, so that I can use this line

```
Company.customer
```

in order to select all company which has customer type.

The relationship between Company and CompanyType is many-to-many.

Company:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :name, :website, type_ids
  has_and_belongs_to_many :types, :class_name => "CompanyType"
  #scope :customer, where()
end
```

CompanyType:

```
class CompanyType < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_and_belongs_to_many :companies
end
```

For the table in the database, I have table "company_types", "company_types_companies" (connection table between company_types and companies) and "companies"

How do I fill in :customer scope in Company model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

```
scope :customers, joins(:types).where(company_types: { name: 'customer' })
```

One thing I would like to raise is I think what you're doing is a bit overkill than simply adding a `company_type` column in the companies model.  If you're not using CompanyType for anything else, I suggest you add a column instead of using 2 tables.

Comment: I did using 2 models, because it is many to many relationship. A company can be a customer type and supplier type.

Comment: Yep I get that.  Are you using CompanyType anywhere else? or are you storing some info in company_types? or are you using it to dynamically add company types?  If it's set to just 2 types, it's better to declare a constant that use additional 2 tables.

Comment: I use the table because maybe there will be another type of company to be added later on. So it's going to be easier :D Btw thanks for your help

Comment: yep that should be easier on your part. no need to do a deploy and it will just work :)